# How to force launch4j to run java app including java.exe.manifest

Tags: java, manifest, launch4j

I have an app and when I run it on high resolution monitor I want to include manifests (`java.exe.manifest` / `javaw.exe.manifest`) in order to disable `dpiAware` (`set dpiAware=false`).

So, i added `java.exe.manifest` and `javaw.exe.manifest` for my `jre` (internal `jre`, there is no other `jre` on comp installed) and when I run my app from command line (`java -jar ....`) it looks ok, but when i run using a launcher made with `launch4j` this does not work, app's GUI looks a little bit ugly (checkBoxes are bigger, icons are not properly rendered etc.).

Is it any option in `launch4j` how to do this?

When I start app somehow to force java to read `java.exe.manifest` also. 
By the way,I tried also with "`-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=false`" option, but this does not work.

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display